# Codeigniter routing with :any

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I migrated from Codeigniter 2 to 3. I have controller files in default controller directory as well as inside sub-directory called content and indexes. Current `routes.php` file looks like this:

```
$controller_dir = opendir(APPPATH."controllers");
while (($file = readdir($controller_dir)) !== false) {
    if (substr($file, -4) == ".php" ) {
        $route[substr($file, 0, -4)."(.*)"] = substr($file, 0, -4)."$1";
    } else if (substr($file, -5) == ".php/") {
        $route[substr($file, 0, -5)."(.*)"] = substr($file, 0, -5)."$1";
    }
}

$route['reviews'] = 'content/reviews/index/profile/$1';
$route['money/(:any)'] = 'indexes/money/index/$1';
$route['faq/do-i-need-to-signup'] = 'faq/question_answer';
$route['(:any)'] = 'index/profile/$1';
```

`index/profile/$1` has logic to check username in database. I am using it as www.example.com/robert where robert is dynamic name (consider it as referal name). It was working in CI 2. But, in CI 3 getting 404 error with same code.

What am I missing here? Please ask me if question is not clear.

Comment: You're not supposed to have a controller named "Index". https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html#controller-names

Comment: What file would end with `.php/`?

Answer (score 2):

Now you need specify in route that it will be taking more parameters in query parts. Try this:

```
$route['reviews/(:any)'] = 'content/reviews/index/profile/$1';
```

this should solve the **404 error**. You will be able to access it like: `http://localhost/reviews/robert`

If you want to pass more parameter just specify in route and you it `$number`.

E.g.:

```
$route['reviews/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'content/reviews/index/profile/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved it this way already as of now. But, I want to know if its possible without `reviews` word in the URL.

Comment: you can write any key word like `$route['anyword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'content/reviews/index/profile/$1/$2'`
but its really recommended to use `anyword` as otherwise it won't look for other controllers and try to map on this function.